# PDF invoice items file location in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

I am working on Magento 2 pdf invoice and trying to change layout of default invoice.As I have seen in default Magento pdf there are six column for displaying items in pdf

```
Products
SKU
Price
Qty 
Tax
Subtotal
```

When I have checked in admin email template it is calling layout for displaying all items

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

and in phtml file

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/invoice/items.phtml
```

there are only three column

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items'); ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-qty">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty'); ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-subtotal">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Subtotal'); ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

I am not getting which file is exactly called when

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

layout is loaded.Please help me if anybody know about it.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution? i need the same to customize the default invoice.. share your solutions bro

Answer (score 2):

Below Model class is responsible for displaying items in invoice pdf.

> Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

You need to override this model class.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old post, but thought it may be of help for anyone visiting in future.

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

This handle is reffering to sales_email_order_invoice_items.xml

From this, we can see that it is likely to be inside the module-sales module.
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_invoice_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Invoice Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <update handle="sales_email_order_invoice_renderers"/>
    <update handle="sales_email_item_price"/>
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Invoice\Items" name="items" template="Magento_Sales::email/invoice/items.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.email.order.invoice.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Totals" name="invoice_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="2"</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Inside this file, you can then see the different PHTML files which are being used:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/invoice/items.phtml
vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/templates/order/tax.phtml
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml
```

If you need to edit this files; do not edit the core files directly - Place an over-ride into your theme folder.